# Populate UITableView using NSMutableDictionary, keysSortedByValueUsingSelector

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

My model class has a NSMutableDictionary with my data.  In my view class, I want to display that data in my UITableView cellforRowAtIndexPath method.  My view class has an NSArray for the data to display.

I can do this to get my data into my NSArray to display correctly:

```
self.CategoriesArray = [model.CategoryDictionary allKeys];
```

However, since NSMutableDictionary does not sort on its own, my items in my TableView are not in alphabetical order.  I thought I could do this:

However, I get the following error:

```
2Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFBoolean localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13d0a20'
```

I'm assuming that's because my view class doesn't know what to do with the localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare method.

How do I solve this problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were saying that this gives you the correct results, just not in order, right?

```
self.CategoriesArray = [model.CategoryDictionary allKeys];
```

If that's the case, then this will give you the correct order if I'm understanding your question correctly:

```
NSArray* keys = [model.CategoryDictionary allKeys];

self.CategoriesArray = [keys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

`localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` is only to compare NSString, not NSDictionary or NSArray.

To sort your categoriesArray look at

`sortedArrayUsingComparator:` and `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` for NSArray

`sortUsingDescriptors` and `sortUsingComparator` for NSMutableArray

To loop through your array you can do something like

```
for (NSString *string in categoriesArray)
{

}
```

Comment: the elements in my array are nsstrings though.  Can I not use the localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare method?

Comment: You'll need to loop through the array. You can't call a method meant for a string on an array. I'll edit my answer with more details.